# jquery highlight input boxes when credentials are wrong when logging in to website

Tags: jquery, html, forms, authentication

I'm not sure why I can't get this to function correctly like in my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uRvF6/

Perhaps it's because my post action is directing to another page? Maybe it's actually working but because of the url change i'm not seeing it?

```
<script> 


$('#loginForm').submit(function(){
     var vals = $('.nomargin').val()
     if (!vals) 
        {
          console.log('Error exists');
          $('.nomargin').attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:#FF0000 1px solid;");
          $('.nomargin').val('enter a value');
        }  
    return false;
});        
</script> 

        <div class="loginBox clearMeFocus">
                <form action="client_homepage.dhtml" method="post" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" >

<input type="hidden" name="site" id="site" value="free">

                    <h3>Agent Log In</h3>
                    <div style="float: left; font-size: 10px; color: red; margin-top: -8px; position: absolute;"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" title="username" class="nomargin">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" title="password">
                        <input type="image" src="images/submit.png" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" alt="submit">
                    </div>
                    <h6><a href="/join.dhtml">Not an Associate?</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/password.html">Forgot Password?</a></h6>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning false outside the condition, so the form will never be submitted, update it as follows:

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function(){
 var vals = $('.nomargin').val()
 if (!vals || vals=="") 
    {
      console.log('Error exists');
      $('.nomargin').attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:#FF0000 1px solid;");
      $('.nomargin').val('enter a value');
        return false;
    }  
});
```

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/uRvF6/4/)

Comment: I still can't get it to work, i feel that it's because when i submit even if it's wrong it changes pages.

Comment: @cookinggood P.s your original fiddle will never work even if correct value is entered,the value since you are always returning false from your submit function.

Comment: if it fails it doesn't highlight it just moves to login_failed.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49429/discussion-between-cooking-good-and-tilwin-joy)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#submit_form').submit(function(){
     var vals = $('.validate').val()
     if (vals == '') //changed this from !val to == ''
        {
          console.log('Error exists');
          $('.validate').attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:#FF0000 1px solid;");
          $('.validate').val('enter a value');
        }  
    return false;
});
```

Comment: didn't work.. but maybe because i need to add `$( document ).ready(function)` ???

Comment: with "Try {" did you mean to use the `try` keyword..? If not you should remove the `{` block after that to avoid confusion